# How can I process this curl request?

Tags: php, json, xml, curl

I'm a front-end developer tasked with exporting macros from desk.com using a curl request, and I'm wondering how do I process this code? Do I write a script (and with what language) or can I run this through a command line console? Some basic guidance as to which tools I need to use would be extremely helpful.

Here's the curl request:

```
$ curl https://yoursite.desk.com/api/v2/macros/:id \
-u email:password \
-H 'Accept: application/json'
```

I know this approach to learning is unconventional but with some basic guidance I believe I can figure this out and potentially open new back-end learning opportunities.

Comment: You can run it in the command line if curl is installed on your OS.

Comment: This one comment made everything click. Thank you for not berating my off-kilter approach. I now feel empowered to learn a lot more on my own knowing the general path I'm on.

Comment: It is all about PHP cURL with basic auth. You just need a code example. There are lots on stackoverflow.